# Uploading Img to HTML canvas with proper aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to upload an Img to a HTML-Canvas and want to see it immediately after uploading finished. How can I maintain the proper aspect ratio for the images?

1. Huge images have to be resized to a given canvas size because they shouldn't be allowed to fill the entire viewport.
2. Small images should get a resizing, too, to fill the canvas.
3. Only making use of HTML + CSS + vanilla JS

What I did so far:

```
var fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
var canvas  = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image()

function scaleImage() {
    const windowWidth = window.screen.width
    const windowHeight = window.screen.height

    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var scaledWidth, scaledHeight;
    
    if(img.width > img.height){
        scaledWidth = ctx.canvas.width;
        scaledHeight = (ctx.canvas.width / img.width) * img.height
    }else if(img.width < img.height){
        scaledWidth = (ctx.canvas.height / img.height) * img.width
        scaledHeight = ctx.canvas.height;
    }else{
        scaledWidth = ctx.canvas.width;
        scaledHeight = ctx.canvas.height;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(
        img, 
        (ctx.canvas.width / 2) - (scaledWidth / 2), 
        (ctx.canvas.height / 2) - (scaledHeight / 2), 
        scaledWidth, 
        scaledHeight
    );
};

// readImage ersetzt das Bild
function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
            this.img = img
            this.img.src = e.target.result;
            img.onload = scaleImage
        };       
        fileReader.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

fileUpload.onchange = readImage;

window.onresize = scaleImage;
```

I can upload an Img-File and display it. It's not really fitting the canvas size and if I resize my browser window it keeps resizing and getting bigger beyond the borders of my canvas.

Comment: What have you attempted to do so far?

Comment: I drew a canvas (rectangle) via CSS, no ideas for the script how to read a file and display it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: _Welcome to SO, provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem, I make the following question from your given information: "When i upload an img to a html-canvas i want to maintain it to the proper aspect ratio."_ - Extracted from Gijs Bijl's answer.

Comment: @ArnavThorat I edited my post and provided further information

Answer (score -1):

If you want a max size for an image after uploading, you can use the css max-width attribute. if this image is in a div you can add a width to the div and make the image max-width - auto or 100%

the code would be something like this

```css
.width-100{

width: 100px;

}

.100{

max-width:100%

}
```

```html
<div  class="width-100">
<img class="100" src="example" alt="example">
</div>
```

Comment: I've removed the starting of your answer, as it would be more appropriate as a comment. Don't worry - I've replied to the OP your introduction!

Comment: I have a visible canvas with borders. While resizing the window, it doesn't fit in the canvas properly. I provided my JS Code in my origin post